# Invalid string length RangeError in Vue only certain enviroments

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I have a Vue component in production and a testing environment. In production its within a wordpress theme and I get the error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
    at repeat$1 (vue.js:11398)
    at generateCodeFrame (vue.js:11380)
    at vue.js:11467
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compileToFunctions (vue.js:11464)
    at Vue.$mount (vue.js:11688)
    at Vue._init (vue.js:4901)
    at new Vue (vue.js:4967)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):234)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
```

In testing I just am using a stand alone file and I get not error and the component works fine. I assume there is something different within the Wordpress and Server that causes the error.

From what I read its just a long string that causes the error but how do you fix it if you cant repeat the error locally? Is there any common "Got Ya's" with Wordpress?

The component itself is very straight forward:

```
 <div v-for="event in events" style="    margin: 10px;" v-if="events">
                                <button class="accordion" @click="show">
                                    <a :href="event.url"> Buy Now </a>
                                    <p v-text="event.name.text"></p>
                                    <span class="date">{{ event.start.local | date }}</span>
                                    <span class="capacity" v-if="event.capacity"> Capacity: <span v-text="event.capacity"></span></span>

                                </button>

                                <div class="panel">
                                  <div class="accordian-body" v-html="event.description.html"></div>
                                  <a :href="event.url" class="buy-bottom"> Buy Now </a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    // Using a basic set of effect
                    var vm = new Vue({
                        el: '#main',
                        data: {

                                events: <?php echo json_encode($another); ?>, 
                        },

                        filters: {
                            date: function (value) {
                                return moment(value).format("dddd, MMM Do");   
                            }
                        },
                        mounted: function () {

                            console.log(this.events)
                            this.$nextTick(function () {
                                // code that assumes this.$el is in-document


                                var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                                var i;

                                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                                    acc[i].onclick = function(){
                                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                                        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        },
                        methods:{
                            show: function(event){

                                var clickedElement = event.target;
                                $(clickedElement).siblings('panel').toggle("show");
                            }
                        }
                    })

                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is misleading. I had a similar issue and found that it's a problem with the inline template. There was a style tag, which was causing the issue in my project. 
In your case, I think the problem is in the data object. Use string literal in your events data object like this and it should work:

```
data: {

            events: `<?php echo json_encode($another); ?>`,
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, that error is super misleading. And seems hard to actually find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This error was described and solved here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9504

Error in the template generates error in JS due to bug in generateCodeFrame() or repeat$1() (may be fixed in in one way or another).

Answer (score 0):

## Another case

In my case, this error was caused because I repeat the same HTML attribute

```
<div class="awesome wow"
     class="anotherawesome">
</div>
```

This will raise the same issue.

## Solution

```
<div class="awesome wow anotherawesome">
</div>
```